# How to navigate from a sap ui5 pie chart to sap ui5 bar chart on selectData event?

Tags: charts, sapui5, pie-chart

I have created a vizFrame Pie chart that consumes data from a sample ODATA service.My requirement is that I needed to navigate from that Pie Chart to another Bar Chart on click of a particular section of a pie.The bar chart should  show only that section details which was clicked in the pie chart.For eg.In my example,when i click on Notebooks section in my pie chart,It should show only Notebook details in my Bar chart,which appears in the next view.I used the "selectData" event of vizframe.But I have no idea how to implement this.Please find below my Pie chart view code and the Pie chart  Output that i receive.Can anyone help me with the code?

[Pie_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW0rg.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJcVB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use attachSelectData method of the sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame ([api reference](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame.html#attachSelectData)). You can set it as follows in the controller.js (this handler of event will be raised when user clicks on some data in the graph):

```
var oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("yourVizFrameId");    
oVizFrame.attachSelectData(this.attachSelectData, this, false);
```

And you can get chosen data as follows:

```
attachSelectData : function(oEvent){
   var aData = oEvent.getParameter("data");
},
```